# Can I call a Web Service from SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2005

I want to call a web service from my SQL code, but it cannot be using CLR code.
Can this even be done?

Comment: What kind of SQL code do you want to call the service from? Can you give an example?

Comment: The plan was to have my sproc call out to a web service, fetch some data from there and update the tables locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done through SSIS or using the Object Automation extended stored procedures and [the XMLHTTP server object](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx).

SSIS would be the much preferred way of doing it.